# Python path confusion: can import directory but not files?

Tags: python

I'm struggling with Python paths. I want to be able to import a file from a directory. I can do this when it's available from the filesystem, but not when I'm relying on my PATH (update: or PYTHONPATH) to find it.

Here are the symptoms. First of all, check that my current directory is on my PATH:

```
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds/myapp $ pwd
/Users/me/Dropbox/gds/myapp
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds/myapp $ echo $PATH
... :/usr/local/go/bin:.:/Users/me/Dropbox/gds/myapp
```

And check that `test/test_app` is where I think it is (and has an `__init__.py` in the directory:

```
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds/myapp $ ls tests/
__init__.py __pycache__ test_app.py test_views.py
```

Now check that Python can import `test/test_app` from this directory:

```
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds/myapp $ python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 29 2015, 13:46:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tests
>>> import tests.test_app
>>> exit()
```

All good so far. Now move to a different directory, and see if I can import `test/test_app`:

```
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds/myapp $ cd ..
(.venv)~/Dropbox/gds $ python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 29 2015, 13:46:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tests
>>> import tests.test_app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tests.test_app'
```

But `/Users/me/Dropbox/gds/myapp` is on my PATH, and I can import the directory, so why can't I import this file?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the suggestions. Just tried doing `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/me/Dropbox/gds/myapp`: but still see the same problem when I run Python.

Comment: please, limit your question to a single issue, namely: your PATH vs. PYTHONPATH confusion. The part after the update should be asked as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

The directory needs to be in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), not `PATH` (which is for regular non-Python command lookup).

Comment: Thanks. Just tried doing `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/me/Dropbox/gds/myapp`, but still the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably another `tests` Python package in `sys.path`. Check `tests.__file__` to confirm. To fix it, use more specific names e.g., `myapp.tests` instead i.e., move `tests` package inside `myapp` Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't use `PATH`. It uses the [`PYTHONPATH` variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to look up modules:

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s `PATH`: one or more directory pathnames separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows).

`PATH` is a variable used by your shell to look up binaries; only the *format* (how paths are specified and separated) is shared.